# Generar números aleatorios distintos en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Necesito generar 54 números aleatorios distintos que vayan del 1 al 54.
He hecho un algoritmo, pero este no devuelve 54 números.

```js
function generador() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (54 - 1)) + 1;
}

const cartas = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 54; i++) {
  n = generador();

  if (cartas.includes(n)) {
    console.log(`match en ${n}`)
  } else {
    cartas.push(n)
  }
}


console.table(cartas);
```

Comment: No genera 54 porque si genera uno ya generado anteriormente, lo descarta.

Comment: Como puedo hacer que en lugar de descartarlo, lo reemplaze por otro distinto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como mencioné, el problema está en tener un *loop* con `54` vueltas, pero no en todas las vueltas añades un número a tu *array*, dependiendo de si el número ya se había generado o no.

La solución pasa por generar números que no existan en el *array*.

```
const contains = (n, arr) => arr.includes(n);

const generator = (from, to, arr) => {
    const n = Math.floor(Math.random() * to) + from;
    return contains(n, arr)
           ? generator(from, to, arr)
           : n;
}
```

`#contains` es una función recursiva que genera un número aleatorio. Si este número existe en el *array*, generará otro; si no existe, lo devuelve.

Des del método principal, sólo hace falta llamar al generador y nos aseguramos que el número que devuelve no existe en el *array*.

```
const cartas = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 54; ++i) {
    const n = generator(1, 54, cartas);
    cartas.push(n);
}

console.table(cartas);
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Gracias, fue sumamente útil

Answer (score 0):

El hecho de que no genere los 54 números se debe a que siempre estas incrementando la variable `i`.

Supongamos que para:

- `i=0`, el número obtenido es `7`, como no se encuentra en `cartas`, lo agregas e incrementas la variable.
- `i=1`, el número obtenido es `7`, como ya se encuentra en `cartas`, no lo agregas e incrementas la variable.

Es por este tipo de casos que nunca vas a obtener los `54`.

La solución *"lógica"* sería solamente incrementar la variable `i` solo cuando el número no se encuentra en el arreglo `cartas`, pero el problema que esto generaría sería de performance y en el pero de los casos un bucle infinito (*puede que "nunca" salga el número que te falta generar*).

### Solución

Una solución que podrías aplicar es crear el arreglo con los `54` número y luego ordenarlo de forma aleatoria ([Fisher–Yates Shuffle](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/)).

#### Demo:

```js
function shuffle(array) {
  var m = array.length,
    t, i;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (m) {

    // Pick a remaining element…
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

    // And swap it with the current element.
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }
  return array;
}

// Creamos el arreglo con 55 posiciones, obtenemos las claves y quitamos el primero (el 0)
let cartas = [...Array(55).keys()].slice(1);
console.log(JSON.stringify(cartas))
// Ordenamos aleatoriamente
console.log(JSON.stringify(shuffle(cartas)))
```

Comment: Gracias, Marcos, bastante ingenioso